# ¿Cómo obtengo los valores de un diccionario que contiene otro dicccionario en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo este diccionario, sin embargo no se cómo obtener las claves por ejemplo:

```
G = {'a':{'b':3, 'c':4},
     'b':{'a':3, 'c':5},
     'c':{'a':4,'b':5},
   }
```

obtener : `k ={a,b,c}  v ={(3,4),(3,5),(4,5)}`

Comment: Intenta un ciclo `for` usando `G.items()` si es Python3.

Answer (score 1):

si he entendido bién tu problema lo que en realidad quieres es agrupar los diccionarios anidados, Existen muchas formas de hacerlo, una posible solución es agruparlos en un diccionario haciendo uso de [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

G = {'a':{'b':3, 'c':4},
     'b':{'a':3, 'c':5},
     'c':{'a':4,'b':5}}

#Instanciamos un defaultdict que tendrá una lista como valor en todos los casos.
result = defaultdict(list)

#recorremos nuestro diccionario y vamos agrupando por clave los distintos valores de cada diccionario anidado.
for d in G.values():
    for k,v in d.items():
        result[k].append(v)

#Podemos imprimir el diccionario, obtener sus claves         
k = list(result.keys())
v = list(result.values())
print('Diccionario agrupado:', dict(result))
print('Lista de claves:', k)
print('Lista de valores:', v)


#También podemos construir las listas k y v iterando sobre el diccionario
#Por ejemplo de la siguiente forma nos las da ordenadas según la clave
k, v = list(), list()
for key, value in sorted(result.items()):
    k.append(key)
    v.append(value)
print('Lista de claves ordenadas:', k)
print('Lista de valores ordenados por clave:', v)
```

Esto nos da una salida:

> Diccionario agrupado: {'b': [5, 3], 'c': [5, 4], 'a': [3, 4]}
> Lista de claves: ['b', 'c', 'a']
> Lista de valores: [[5, 3], [5, 4], [3, 4]]
> Lista de claves ordenadas: ['a', 'b', 'c']
> Lista de valores ordenados por clave: [[3, 4], [5, 3], [5, 4]]

No especificas versión de Python, el código es válido para Python 3.x, si usas Python 2.x y tienes problemas para adaptarlo comentalo.